# Using ffplay to open a video at a specific window location

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg

I need to use ffplay to open a video file, but i need to pass it x,y coordinates so i can have it play the video where I want it to.

As default ffplay simply opens the video at the top left corner.

I've tried searching for options in ffplay but i couldnt find it. 
Also tried using window managers like fluxbox, again couldnt find the command)

Please note that I need to run it as a shell command.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a job for [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml).
Devilspie can be used also.

For instance, if you play best_movie.avi in ffplay, moving the window will be as easy as:

`xdotool search --name best_movie windowmove 100 100`

HTH

Comment: I just want to add/confirm that there is no way to do it with ffplay only. In its source code, there is nothing to set its position (only its size with -x and -y). So an external tool is the way to do it.

Comment: Is it possible on Windows?

Comment: @AlexandrZarubkin: Yes, it can be done on Windows by using the [`MoveWindow`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.movewindow) WinApi call.

Comment: The command below starts ffplay at a specific location at 1800,1000 with 1240x700 window size on my 2nd monitor.
ffplay rtsp://user:password@$HOST_IP:$PORT -window_title amcrest-19 -left 1800 -top 1000 -x 1240 -y 700